# Landscape mode for a viewController in a UITabBarController

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uikit, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have some 10 view controllers contained in a TabBarController. We have a requirement wherein one view controller out of these 10 view controllers should always be displayed in landscape mode.

Now, when we override:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

and return YES only for Landscape mode in such view controllers, it has not effect. The view controller appears in Portrait mode only.

Probably this is done for a good reason, since when the user switches to a tab whose view controller should support only landscape mode, the whole screen components (including the tabbar) should be rotated to landscape mode, which looks awkward.

Am I right in assuming the cause?

Also, what would be the best way to tackle this? Provide an intermediate view controller in portrait mode and then push the landscape view controllers through it?

Thanks,
Raj